# How to enable GPU working on Anaconda env? I set up everything

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu

I used a Ubuntu 18 VM with a Nvidia Tesla T4.   I installed the corrected tensorflow version 1.15 with GPU support but still cannot get GPU working in the jupyter notebook.  How to deal with this problem..  I believe the driver is set up successfully

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 440.33.01    Driver Version: 440.33.01    CUDA Version: 10.2     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Tesla P4            On   | 00000000:00:04.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   35C    P8     7W /  75W |      0MiB /  7611MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
(base) koruplato@instance-1:~$ nvcc --version
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2019 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Wed_Oct_23_19:24:38_PDT_2019
Cuda compilation tools, release 10.2, V10.2.89
```

it's said that

````
print("Num GPUs Available: ", len(tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')))

Num GPUs Available:  0```
````

Answer (score 0):

As far as i can see you have CUDA 10.2. Tensorflow works only with CUDA 10.0 as described here: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu.

Also you need to get the cuDNN SDK (>=7.4.1)

Hope that helps